# Prestahop 1.7.6 How to remove/disable Product page?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

How can i remove/disable product page? I just wanted the homepage and quick view only.

How can be this done? anyone can guide me?

[image: Product page]

Answer (score 0):

try writing false if condition for the product page.
Then that code will not be executed.

ex:

```
<?php
if (false) { ?>
    <p>Product page</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow my steps, please:

1. Enter folder list of PS.
2. Find themes folder > enter it.
3. Find current theme's folder > enter it.
4. Inside this folder find temples > catalog > _partials > miniatures. Here you will see "product.tpl" file. Open it in text editor.

At the beginning you will see code like that:

```
{block name='product_thumbnail'}
                        <a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
                            <img
                                src = "{$product.cover.bySize.home_default.url}"
                                alt = "{if !empty($product.cover.legend)}{$product.cover.legend}{else}{$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}{/if}"
                                data-full-size-image-url = "{$product.cover.large.url}" />
                        </a>
                    {/block}
```

He you need to remove `<a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">` and `</a>`, then save the file + clear cache of the shop + check the result.

Solution was provided by a member **[PrestaServicePro](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/profile/1614254-prestaservicepro/)** from prestashop community forum.